# ASP.NET 3.0. Date in seconds cannot be converted from JSON to System.Date within POST request

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

I want to test my POST endpoint with simple request with JSON in its body.

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 project with one single controller and one endpoint inside it. I created empty ASP.NET Core project primarily.
Then I created a simple controller in order to process POST requests.

```
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class UpdateController : Controller
    {
        // POST api/update
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Post(Update update)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
```

`Update` class is a type from `Telegram.Bot.Types`

When I try to test my POST action method with following data in a body:

```
    {
    "update_id":10000,
    "message":{
      "date":1441645532,
      "chat":{
         "last_name":"Test Lastname",
         "id":1111111,
         "first_name":"Test",
         "username":"Test"
      },
      "message_id":1365,
      "from":{
         "last_name":"Test Lastname",
         "id":1111111,
         "first_name":"Test",
         "username":"Test"
      },
      "text":"/start"
      }
    }
```

I get the following error:
`The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.message.date | LineNumber: 3 | BytePositionInLine: 19.`

But I expected it would work fine.

I've already checked `Message` type in Telegram's repository. `Message` type belongs to `Update` one as a property.

And date there is marked with `UnixDateTimeConverter`:

```
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(UnixDateTimeConverter))]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

I've also tried to deserialize JSON from above using Newtonsoft.JSON and it did right without any errors. But still have a problem to get it done via ASP.NET Core 3.0 project.

Comment: You can still use JSON.Net in a .Net Core 3.0 project. It's just that it's not the default anymore.

Comment: @phuzi Thanks, it did the trick. I missed somehow that JSON.NET is not a default library there.

Comment: install nuget package

Comment: @Gauravsa yes. did that as well. thanks!

Comment: @phuzi Could you please put an answer? I'll vote for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From ASP.NET Core 3.0, Json.NET is no longer included as the default JSON (de)serializer, that role has been given to System.Text.Json.

In a lot of cases this will be sufficient. System.Text.Json cannot be used instead of Json.NET in all cases though - this is on purpose as it is supposed to be lightweight. However you can still use Json.NET in ASP.Net Core 3.0 if System.Text.Json just doesn't cater for your needs.

Form Immo Landwerth's blog post [Try the new System.Text.Json APIs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) there's a section on [Integration with ASP.NET Core MVC](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-blog/blob/master/2019/06-Jun/json/2019-06-json.md#integration-with-aspnet-core-mvc)

> If you’d like to switch back to the previous default of using Newtonsoft.Json, do the following:
>
> 1. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson NuGet package.
> 2. In ConfigureServices() add a call to AddNewtonsoftJson()
>
> ```
> public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>  {
>      ...
>      services.AddControllers()
> +            .AddNewtonsoftJson()
>      ...
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JavaScriptDateTimeConverter))]
```

Do a double dataannotation otherwise you would have to write your own custom converter.

Comment: I'm not able to do a double data annotation, because I don't own that type. Or what do you mean?